# Serialize class with version?

Tags: actionscript-3, serialization

If I serialize a class in AS3:

```
var obj:CustomClass = new CustomClass();

var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeObject(obj);
```

Lets say I store those bytes in a database and retrieve them at a later date:

```
var obj:CustomClass = (CustomClass)bytes.readObject();
```

What if I made a change to that class in that time. That cast would fail. Is there anyway I could differentiate between the 2 ByteArrays and determine that a change to the class has been made?